# How to uniformly change color of an image?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, colors, image-processing, photoshop-cs5

I have an image that is kind of reddish/orange:
[image]

Is there a tool (e.g. Photoshop, Paint.NET, etc...) that let's me pick a different color set (say green) and that would color the image accordingly.  For instance, pieces that are dark red would be dark green, pieces that are light red would be light green, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've achieved this effect in GIMP by playing around with the Tint and Color levels, accomplishing things like very convincingly changing people's eye color in photos (e.g. took a photo of a brown-eyed friend and gave her blue eyes). Also very unnatural -- but still convincing -- transformations, like flame-red eyes! The only trick to it is to be sure to first select the area(s) you want to change the colors in, otherwise you end up with your entire image going all wonky on you and looking like crap, and everything beyond that is just experimenting until you achieve the effect you want -- since that is a very subjective thing, I can't give you a step-by-step walkthrough because I don't know what precisely you want to change.

I have no doubt that Photoshop could achieve the same thing (probably with very similarly-named tools, in fact).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is very easy in Photoshop, and a lot of fun.  There are many ways to do it.

A classic way would be to make a selection of the area you want to change, using the various tools you can use for that, and then make it into a Quick Mask, then refining and feathering the selection in that view, and then overlaying a Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer to change the tone.

There are other ways too, [as shown on this webpage](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/changing-color-in-photoshop).  I think looking for tutorials on using the [**Colour Replacement Tool**](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&q=Photoshop+%22(Colour+OR+Color)+Replacement+Tool%22+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=38584de721edb593&ion=1) may be your best avenue.